# Windows 8 can't update

Tags: windows-8

I'm currently trying to update an old machine at work, but the windows auto update seems to go nowhere.

[image]

Its just running like that, for days, and nothing happens. We are now in 2017, and it seems, with the 'Most recent check for updates' information, that my computer didn't have a ping back from Microsoft's servers since Dec. 2014.

If it can help, here is what is under Update History

[image]

Also, updating to Win10 would be the last resort option. We would like to keep the computer on Win8, not have to waste a day on setup.

So what can I do to force my computer to go get the updates?

Comment: Try this [options](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_other-windows_install/fix-windows-updates-fail-to-install-in-windows-7-8/260f8566-8d0f-4535-817a-be01c6a9d0f7) and let us know.

Comment: Wah thave you tried so far?  Did you run Windows' Windows Update trobleshooter?  Reset the WU cache?    If you havn't already you should be upgrading to at least Windows 8.1 (as 8.0 is not logner supported).

Answer (score 0):

**Sometimes Windows Update itself, needs an update. (Ironic)**

1. Update Windows Update
2. Install Never10 to prevent Upgrade to Win 10.

First make sure that you have the latest "windows update agent".
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/949104/how-to-update-the-windows-update-agent-to-the-latest-version

*Source: https://grc.com/linkfarm (with another ref to context)*

Than download https://grc.com/never10 to prevent win10 upgrades (not updates). Reboot.

After this, regular updates should come in. Good luck!

Comment: I think I'm safe with the Win10 auto-update. They ended the program when you could get it for free. Am I wrong in thinking that?

Comment: Honestly, I would not take the chance ;)